# How to get full path of a specific assembly?

Tags: c#, path, .net-assembly

I need to get a `full path` to the `dll` of an `assembly` that is NOT the executing assembly. For instance, can this be done by `assembly name`?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getassembly(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 var location = Path.GetDirectoryName(typeof(YourType).Assembly.Location);
```

I'm sure there are a bunch of other ways to do this if you google around.